# ruby on rails 4.2.6 "delete action" not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on ruby on rails 4.2.6 , this is my show.html file

```
<h1><%= @post.title %></h1>
<p><%= @post.body %></p>
<p><%= @post.created_at %></p>
<%= link_to "Edit Post",edit_post_path %> | <%=link_to 'Delete Post',@post,method: :delete %>
```

and This is my code inside posts controller

```
def destroy
 @post = Post.find(params[:id])
 @post.destroy
 redirect to post_path,:notice =>"your post has been deleted"
 end
end
```

The date is not deleting and it is showing and the error coming inside command prompt is

```
action controller::routing error( no routing matches      [get]"/javascripts/default.js)
```

Kindly Help !

Comment: are you using Windows system ?

Comment: Yes I am using windows 7 .

Comment: get rid of your windows box for Ruby on Rails development, try virtual box or any online platform like https://c9.io/  - FYI: The problem is that `DELETE` request is not made in windows rather a `GET` request goes to server and it confuses which action to be executed. And, again the issue is occurring because you have changed your `application.html.erb` file to load `default.js` instead of `application.js`.

Comment: can you provide routes.rb

Comment: Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'categories/index'

  get 'categories/edit'

  get 'categories/new'

  get 'categories/show'

  get 'home/index'
    resources :posts
    resources :categories

end

Answer (score 1):

The destroy method should be:

```
def destroy
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @post.destroy
  redirect_to posts_path, :notice => "your post has been deleted"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

1). The error doesn't mean the "delete action" not working, it's saying that somewhere in your html/erb, you want to load '/javascripts/default.js', but there is no definition for this url in your `config/routes.rb`

2). The `destroy` controller code you provided has a redundant `end`, should be like this:

```
def destroy
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @post.destroy
  redirect to post_path, notice: "your post has been deleted"
end
```

3). I think your server should log some exceptions for that syntax error, whenever something goes wrong, the log file should be the first few things you check.

Comment: Well I think your first point looks relevant , Can you please explain  a bit more how to go about it . I am new to this . !!

Comment: Could you paste the server log file in your question? Or the request was never made it to the server?

Comment: Started GET "/javascripts/default.js" for ::1 at 2016-06-20 13:52:54 +0530

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/javascripts/default.js"):

Comment: Then the problem is you didn't load JavaScript file correctly, and that click doesn't fire a request to backend at all.

Comment: So how should I proceed with this ?  I have changed my application.html.erb where I have changed "application" to "default" !!

Comment: You should not do that, switch back to what it used to be. `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>`

Comment: But when I do that I am getting the error:-
Showing c:/ruby/rails/firstapp/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #5 raised:
TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: Did you edit sth in that application js/coffee file?

Comment: Where I am going to do that and what updates does it need ?

Answer (score 0):

in your controller

```
redirect to post_path
```

is wrong you are redirecting to show page you will need to redirect on index page.

```
redirect to posts_path
```